# Seleccionar fecha desde input tipo date y sumarle días a esa fecha a partir de ese input en PHP Y JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Buenas tengo un formulario que es para agregar un periodo lectivo. Los campos son ***id_pl***, ***descripcion_pl***, ***inicio_pl***, ***finalizacion_pl***
Lo que necesito es que cuando selecciono la fecha de inicio automáticamente a esa fecha se le sumen 40 semanas y que esa fecha sea ***finalizacion_pl*** y aparezca automáticamente, eh visto en otras publicación pero solo le hacen con la fecha actual
De antemano gracias, adjunto el formulario

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="container">         
        <div class="form_register">
            <div class="titulo">
            <form action="" method="post">
            <label for="Descripcion"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>          Descripcion:</label>
            <input type="text" name="descripcion_pl" id="Descripcion" placeholder="Descripcion de periodo lectivo" required>
            <label for="Inicio de periodo lectivo"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Inicio de periodo lectivo:</label>
            <input type="date" name="inicio_pl" id="Inicio de periodo lectivo" placeholder="Inicio de periodo lectivo" required>
            <label for="Finalizacion de periodo lectivo:"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Finalizacion de periodo lectivo:</label>
            <input type="date" name="finalizacion_pl" id="Finalizacion de periodo lectivo:" placeholder="Finalizacion de periodo lectivo" required>
            <input type="submit" value="&#128190; Guardar"  class="btn_save">
            </form>

            <br>
        </div>


    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EL concepto a aplicar va muy de la mano del que dices que ya revisaste de la fecha actual.

Quedaria algo asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="container">         
        <div class="form_register">
            <div class="titulo">
            <form action="" method="post">
            <label for="Descripcion"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>          Descripcion:</label>
            <input type="text" name="descripcion_pl" id="Descripcion" placeholder="Descripcion de periodo lectivo" required>
            <label for="Inicio de periodo lectivo"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Inicio de periodo lectivo:</label>
            <input type="date" name="inicio_pl" id="Inicio de periodo lectivo" placeholder="Inicio de periodo lectivo" required onchange="calcularFechaFin(this.value)">
            <label for="Finalizacion de periodo lectivo:"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Finalizacion de periodo lectivo:</label>
            <input type="date" name="finalizacion_pl" id="Finalizacion de periodo lectivo:" placeholder="Finalizacion de periodo lectivo" required>
            <input type="submit" value="&#128190; Guardar"  class="btn_save">
            </form>

            <br>
        </div>


    </section>
</body>

<script>
    function calcularFechaFin(fecha) {
        var semanas = 40
        fecha = new Date(fecha)
        fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + (semanas * 7));
        document.getElementsByName('finalizacion_pl')[0].valueAsDate  = fecha
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Entendiendo que se hace calculo plano de 40 semanas se añade a la fecha 7 * 40 que serian los dias que corresponden a dicho periodo y se añade el resultado al campo *finalizacion_pl*. Finalmente, si el campo *finalizacion_pl* se va a llenar solo, quiza deberias ponerlo como disabled asi no se permite al usuario llenarlo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias si me funciono :)